# Display from first row of array lists in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of lists which is getting from the db. It is displayed as row in the console. That is from row[0] to row[10]. What i want is i need to hide the row[0] and display the remaining row[1] to row[10]. Only need is hide the first list/row. i am using angular 8 . How to do this?

Comment: where you display your array of object? and how?

Comment: Share the code you are using on the template.

Comment: @john pelase go through my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo** For Use-case One in this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbc7cx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Working Demo** For Use-case Two in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4eqp1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**1. *If you want to filter record in component file then..***

```
     this.arrays = this.arrays.filter((value, i) => i !== 0);
```

By filtering you can remove first row[0] and only display rest record of objects only.

Template is

```
<div *ngFor="let row of arrays; let i = index">
   <ng-container>
     {{row | json}}
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

**2. *If you want to filter intemplate then below code is working for you..***

**template.html is**

```
<div *ngFor="let row of arrays; let i = index">
   <ng-container *ngIf=" i !== 0 " >
      {{row | json}}
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

**component.ts file is**

```
arrays = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Row 1'
},
{  
  id: 2,
  name: 'Row 2'
},{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Row 3'
},{
  id: 4,
  name: 'Row 5'
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let row of array; let first = first">
<ng-container *ngIf="!first" >
  {{row}}
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Using first will make code more readable. (Check documentation for more in ngFor)